# How to set up in-memory database in ClientDataSource?

Tags: java, junit4, derby

First I was using this way how to get connection and all was fine.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:memory:datab;create=true");
```

But now I have to change it to DataSource and how I find out derby had class ClientDataSource for this, but for the hell I can't find out how to setup that virtual DB in JUnit tests.

```
ClientDataSource ds = new ClientDataSource();
con = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: See https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyClientSpec.html

Comment: I read that all but I didn't find out.

Comment: In what environment are you using Derby? Standalone, Application Server, Unit Tests, ...?

Comment: Like I told JUnit Tests

Comment: You did not tell in the text of your question. Please post the relevant parts of your test code. And please describe in more detail what doesn't work.

Comment: So I finde out that `ClientDataSource ds = new ClientDataSource();  ds.setDatabaseName("sampleDB;create=true");` is working. Problem was that I was trying `ds.setDatabaseName("jdbc:derby:memory:sampleDB;create=true");`

Comment: What problem? Do you get an error? Please include the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Since I found this question during my googling :

The answer is to use the [EmbeddedDataSource](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/publishedapi/org/apache/derby/jdbc/EmbeddedDataSource.html) instead of the `ClientDataSource` and to keep the "memory:" prefix before the database name

```
import org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource;
...
EmbeddedDataSource ds = new EmbeddedDataSource();

ds.setDatabaseName("memory:" + "datab");
ds.setCreateDatabase("create");
ds.setUser("user");
ds.setPassword("pwd");
```